# UFW BLOCK on syslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ufw

I was able to see this "UFW BLOCK" in Syslog at different times.

> Dec 15 01:22:23 node1 kernel: [4837640.303204] [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s2 OUT= MAC=xx:xx:xx SRC=192.168.x.x DST=192.168.x.x LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=29016 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33988 DPT=4000 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0

This is not constantly seen, but once per day in recent days.

Comment: the SRC and DST "192.168.x.x" Ip addresses are devices on your LAN - do you know what devices have those IP addresses (by the way, no need to "hide" private non routable IP addresses)

Answer (score 0):

Something on your LAN is trying to reach port 4000/TCP on your (Ubuntu?) machine.

Could be a lot of things, you should probably check the machine from which the traffic originates.
I am assuming that the DST (destination IP) is the same machine that is blocking the traffic but you are not giving us much to go on.